# Pentaho Report Designer Dynamic Heights

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have a report with 3 columns, ITEM, DESCRIPTION and QTY.

The ITEM and QTY fields are single line values, however the description is multi line, can be 1 line, can be 30 lines, or any number in between.

The problem is the ITEM and QTY columns do not grow to the same height as the description column and the vertical borders of QTY and ITEM fields do not stretch to the height of the DESCRIPTION field despite the fact that the dynamic-height property is set for all of the fields.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 6):

Following solution worked in PRD 3.9, I hope it will help you too:

1. Set `height` for each item (label or field) in the row to `100%`.
2. Set `dynamic-height` of the band, which contains these fields, to true.

Thus, the band will increase it's size, so that each field will fit into the band. And then each item in the band will be stretched to fill the band.

Please note, that dynamic-height **may also lead to collapsing empty rows**, if the height of your band is set to 0.

Comment: This still worked as a solution in Pentaho 6.1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also working years later, in Pentaho 9.1. You saved my day. Thank you.